# GGTS can't run Groovy Shell

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, ggts

I'm using the Groovy Grails Tool Suite to practice Groovy. I want to run a Groovy Shell, but when I create a new shell and try to run it, I get this error:

```
Could not find $jarName on the class path.  Please add it manually
```

What does this mean, and how do I resolve this?

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: There are so many things that could cause this error. I ended up fixing it in that instance, but I don't remember exactly what I did that time around. This usually means that something is not configured correctly for your class path in your IDE. If you are having this error, go ahead and create a new question and comment the link to it here, and I'll try to help out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because JLine can't be found on your classpath.  I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/pull/131/) to make the error message in this case actually useful.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with this exact same message, but the reason was that I was attempting to run the script without specifying which script to run. Ensure you have the script open in the editing window and trying running it again - that got rid of the message for me.